# Можете пожалуйста объяснить как устроенная в mongodb эта папка, что значат эти файлы

Tags: docker, mongodb, резервное-копирование

Я хочу сделать backup из docker контейнера. но проблема в том что когда я копирую всю эту папку на скриншоте целиком куда то вне контейнера c помощью docker cp,а потом обратно передаю в контейнер (так сказать после удаления контейнра с вольюмом,чтобы так сказать проверить мой backup) я непонимаю как правильно прописать команду mongorestore,чтобы он восстановил мою бд,тк не могу понять что делать со всеми этими файлами.Подскажите пожалуйста!![image]

Comment: По идее никакого mongorestore не нужно, база должна начать работать с этими файлами.

Comment: Проблема в том,что вот когда я пересоздаю контейнер,у меня так же создаётся экземпляр монги в этом новом контейнере так и я ещё потом добавляю свою бд из вне,получается у нас два экземпляра монги в контейнере Ия не могу понять,с каким экземпляром общаемся контейнер,подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Нет, от переноса файлов никакой второй экземпляр не появляется.

Comment: /data/db - это путь папкив контейнере где находится моя бд.Вот я ее копирую куда то на компьютер из контейнера,а потом создаю новый контейнер с вольюмом и уже с компа отправляю так же с помощью docker cp эту бд в папку /data и получается что у меня в /data уже две папки /db тк одна появляется автоматически при создании контейнера .@user7860670

Comment: *"у меня в /data уже две папки /db"* - этого не может быть, так как по одному пути не могут располагаться файловые сущности с одинаковыми именами. И копировать в докер эту папку незачем, примонтируйте ее при создании контейнера.

Comment: То есть нам необязательно создавать volume и указывать его в compose файле( volumes:
      - ourvolume:/data/db)таким образом?Можно просто примантировать папку да?

Comment: Да. Собственно даже не факт, что вам вообще нужен compose.

Comment: а утилиты mongodump и mongorestore грубо говоря можно использовать в самом контейнере но не вне,правильно же я понимаю?А например если вне контейнера то dpcker cp и монтирование папки,да?

Comment: mongodump и mongorestore это вообще из другой оперы, они нужны когда вы хотите с работающей базы слить какой-то блок данных или восстановить его

Comment: ну я так и планирую на самом деле)но непонимаю может ли mongodump работать вне контейнера с mongodb.У меня вообще комппоуз файл с монго контейнером и контейнер с сервером.Могу ли я в самом компоуз файле как то примантировать папку?